# force sub-classes to do something when they are being loaded

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, reflection, static

Suppose I want to have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract Operator {

    public int[] operands;

    public Operator(int[] operands) {
        this.operands = operands;
    }

    public abstract int getOperatorResult();
}
```

And some operators to extend from it like:

```
public class Add extends Operator {

    public Add(int[] operands) {
        super(operands);
    }

    public int getOperatorResult() {
        return operands[0] + operands[1];
    }
}
```

And an OperatorCreator which gets an expression like "1+1" and returns the appropriate Operator's sub-class(in this case Add):

```
public class OperatorCreator {

    public static Operator getInstance(String expr) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The main problem:
And I want to let others to design their own operators by extending Operator class. And use their operators  polymorphically. something like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Operator op = OperatorCreator.getInstance("1-2");
        System.out.println(op.getOperatorResult());
    }
}
```

Suppose that OperatorCreator knows where .class files for Operator's sub-classes are located and uses reflection to load these sub-classes at run time.
But OperatorCreator has to know one more thing: It also has to know the operator symbol for these sub-classes to return an Add object when "1+1" is given for example. So any Operator's sub-class can have a static method: "getSymbol" which returns the operator's symbol. But there is a problem. If someone extends Operator and doesn't provide "static getSymbol" her code will compile successfully without providing a mechanism for OperatorCreator to know the symbol of her new Operator's sub-class and it causes run-time problems. And I don't want to make getSymbol an abstract method of Operator to force sub-classes to implement it because I don't want to make an instance of sub-class in order to get it's symbol. How can I force sub-classes to register their symbol when they are being loaded?

Comment: if your JDK is version 8, then in Java 8, interfaces can have static methods, as well as override-able methods with a default implementation. They still can't have instance fields though. These features are part of the lambda expression support. but if your JDK < 8 then I would use interfaces normally and change my static methods to instance ones

Comment: Thanks for these interesting information about JDK 8. But my program is going to run on older JRE s. @RaminOmrani

Comment: The method simply shouldn't be static.

Comment: "*I don't want to make an instance of sub-class*". How do you plan to call the getOperatorResult method without creating a subclass instance? The getInstance method has to create an appropriate instance. I understand that this does not answer your question but not creating an instance of a subclass is anyway not an option here. See my answer.

Comment: I said that I don't want to make myself to create an instance just to call getSymbol. @CKing

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the `Operator` class hierarchy so that it has abstract subclasses for each symbol type, for example `AddOperator`, `SubtractOperator`, `MultiplyOperator`. Now the client provides you the type of the operator by choosing the superclass to extend.